# WebApplication not working properly while running Tomcat as service

Tags: jsp, tomcat7

I have a web application `Infobase.war` created on `eclipse` and hosted on `Tomcat (7.0.27) (OS: Windows server 2003)`. The `index.jsp` of the application navigates to a location on network to access files and display it on a webpage (see the complete `index.jsp` code below).

The problem is that the application works perfectly fine when `Tomcat` is run as `console` by manually running `Startup.bat`.
But if `Tomcat` is run as a `service` (through windows services) the application runs but fails to access the files on the `remote machine` and eventually the webpage gets displayed with the error message put for such cases (non-access)in code.

The `Tomcat` service settings through `tomcat7w.exe` have already been done. The heap limit has been increased.

The code for index.jsp is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Infobase </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$("div#block").load('https://`inggnh018cfr`:8443/infobase/Navigate.do');
    //ADS
    //String path="\\\\"+getServletContext().getInitParameter("server_ip")+getServletContext().getInitParameter("filepath");
    $("div#block").load('https://132.186.18.155:8443/infobase/Navigate.do?f=\\\\132.186.198.175\\\\gc_sl_pg\\Quota\\EFIE\\Documents\\EFIE_new\\1.%20QUALITY');
    $("div#block1").load('https://132.186.18.155:8443/infobase/Navigate.do?f=\\\\132.186.198.175\\\\gc_sl_pg\\Quota\\EFIE\\Documents\\EFIE_new\\2.%20PROCESS');
    $("div#block2").load('https://132.186.18.155:8443/infobase/Navigate.do?f=\\\\132.186.198.175\\\\gc_sl_pg\\Quota\\EFIE\\Documents\\EFIE_new\\3.%20DOCUMENTS');
    $("div#block3").load('https://132.186.18.155:8443/infobase/Navigate.do?f=\\\\132.186.198.175\\\\gc_sl_pg\\Quota\\EFIE\\Documents\\EFIE_new\\4.%20INFORMATION%20HANDBOOK');

});
function expand(){

    // $(obj).click(function(){
        obj=window.event.srcElement;
        if(obj.value=='true'){
        //alert('http://localhost:8080/infobase/Navigate.do?f='+window.event.srcElement.id);
        //$.ajax({url:'https://inggnh018cfr:8443/infobase/Navigate.do?f='+obj.id ,success:function(result){
        $.ajax({url:'https://132.186.18.155:8443/infobase/Navigate.do?f='+obj.id ,success:function(result){
            //alert(result);
            //$(obj).append("<div class='panel' id='div-"+obj.id+"'>"+result+"</div>");
            $(obj).after(result);
            //$("div#"+window.event.srcElement.id).load(result);

        }});

        obj.value='false';
        //alert('http://inggnh018cfr:8080/infobase/ScreenServ.do?f='+obj.firstChild.nodeValue);
        /*screen change*/

        //$.ajax({url:'https://132.186.18.155:8443/infobase/ScreenServ.do?f='+obj.firstChild.nodeValue ,success:function(result){
        $.ajax({url:'https://132.186.18.155:8443/infobase/ScreenServ.do?f='+obj.id,success:function(result){
            //alert(result);

            if(result!=0)
                //document.getElementById("frame").src="\\\\132.186.18.155\\gc_sl_pg\\Deptt_Quota\\EFIE\\Documents\\EFIE\\Obsolete Documents\\PPTs\\"+result;           
            {
                var ppt="\\\\132.186.198.175\\gc_sl_pg\\Quota\\EFIE\\Documents\\EFIE\\Obsolete Documents\\PPTs\\"+result;
                window.open(ppt);
            }
            //else
                //document.getElementById("frame").src="infobase.pps";
            //$(obj).append("<div class='panel' id='div-"+obj.id+"'>"+result+"</div>");
            //$(obj).after(result);
            //$("div#"+window.event.srcElement.id).load(result);

        }});
        }
        else
            if(obj.value=='false'){
                  // alert(obj.firstChild.nodeValue);
                   obj.value='true';
                  // alert(.nodeName);
                   $(obj.nextSibling).remove();
                   //alert('done');
               }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When running from the console, the process runs as the currently logged on user who - it appears - has access to those network locations. When running as a service the process runs as LocalSystem which does not have access to those network locations.

To fix this, create a domain user with the minimum necessary permissions to access those network locations and then configure your service to run as that user.

Comment: Thank you so much Mark, the problem was exactly what you mentioned. Now what I did is, against the LogOn property of Tomcat service (under Windows Server 2003), changed the option from "Local System Account" to the option of "This Account" and put the login credentials of account I was using to start Tomcat as console. And the application is running fine. Thanx once again.